# Why different datatime value, but still duplicate

Tags: mysql

[Mysql Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

> A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. In particular, any fractional part in a value inserted into a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column is stored rather than discarded. With the fractional part included, the format for these values is 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.fraction]', the range for DATETIME values is '1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999',

```
CREATE TABLE `dt_test` (
  `trade_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`trade_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

mysql> insert into dt_test select '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into dt_test select '2022-01-01 00:00:00.120000';
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2022-01-01 00:00:00' for key 'dt_test.PRIMARY'
```

I thought `2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000` is different with `2022-01-01 00:00:00.120000`, so both should insert successfully. But actually only could insert one? What is the reason?

Comment: Please add table definition and insert statement as text

Comment: You must define the column datatype with needed fractional part length (i.e. not `DATETIME` but `DATETIME(6)`). If it is not long enough then the value will be truncated.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is specified in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html. The value you try to insert is rounded when the value doesn't "fit":

> - Inserting a `TIME`, `DATE`, or `TIMESTAMP` value with a fractional seconds part into a column of the same type but having fewer fractional digits results in rounding.

You will not get any errors or warnings:

> No warning or error is given when such rounding occurs. This behavior follows the SQL standard.

This means that even if you specify `2022-01-01 00:00:00.120000` as the value, it is rounded as `2022-01-01 00:00:00` in a `DATETIME(0)` column. This also happens with the value `2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000`, which will result in a duplicate key error message.

Interestingly, the sentence

> In particular, any fractional part in a value inserted into a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column is stored rather than discarded.

on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html is misleading as the  fraction part is not stored (or it *is* stored, but you can't use it in any way).